# How create Activity from Notification intent only when it's not already created?

Tags: android

My app creates a `Notification` from an `IntentService`. When tapped, the `Notification` opens `MainActivity` of type `Activity`. `MainActivity's` `onCreate()` method is called every time a new`Notification` is tapped, irrespective of whether an instance of`MainActivity` is already created or not. Tapping the `Notification` always creates a new instance that replaces the old one.

Is there a way to call `onCreate()` *only if the Activity doesn't exist* and call e.g. `onNewIntent()` if `MainActivity` already exists (or another appropriate method) ?

The `Notification` is currently created like this:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(com.exampleapp.myclient.R.drawable.dummy_notification_icon, "Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, "test", pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

`MainActivity` in Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.exampleapp.myclient.MainActivity"  
    singleTop="true">
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your simply looking for the [android:launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) attribute in the manifest. For your case it should be set to `singleTask`. Then you'll be able to handle the `onNewIntent();` and you'll only have 1 instance.

Comment: Thanks. What's the different between singleTask and singleInstance launchMode?

Comment: @PierreRymiortz you can also visit the link about android:launchmode

Answer (score 3):

You can set the activity as `singleInstance` in `manifest` of the application and when the activity is lauched again the `onCreate()` method will not be called instead of `onNewIntent()` is called. where you can decide what to do next.